# Allow specific users ability to view/open only bugs item

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

I'm not finding a way to allow specific users to view/open only bug items on specific project in TFS 2018.

It's possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You can only restrict users by Area Path, not by work item type.